# Wordpress pagination don't let me go to page 2 (.htaccess redirection I guess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination, wordpress

I have pagination in my post. I did similar thing before, it worked well. Now I was rewriting code to another page and I'am stuck.

For example I have page with pagination:
http://localhost/est/witaj-swiecie/
And I click on page 2 with link:
http://localhost/est/witaj-swiecie/page/2/
And after it return's me back to: 
http://localhost/est/witaj-swiecie/

Before I did it easily on another page but code was a little mess.

My code (with a little cut):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$this->query = array (
    'post_type'              => 'oferta',
    'post_status'            => 'published',
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
);

$big = 999999999;
$post[0]['pagination'] = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => '&laquo; Poprzednia',
    'next_text' => 'Następna &raquo;',
) );
```

Everything is done using Example With a Custom Query:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: Maybe I should change .htaccess to access those pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. I was trying to use those with shortcode on post, not on page. Using it on page solved my problem.